# Query exported from phpmyadmin does not work using mysql_query() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very strange problem here. I am exporting a query through phpmyadmin and then when I run it using `mysql_query` I get an error saying that syntax of the query isn't correct.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cfs_events` ( `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_' at line 14
```

The same query runs perfectly fine using phpmyadmin. What could be the problem?

#### Here is the SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cfs_certificates` (
  `certificate_id` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `emergency_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `certificate_price` enum('40','50') NOT NULL,
  `certificate_order_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_used` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `certificate_id_UNIQUE` (`certificate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cfs_events` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_desc` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `wp_cfs_events` (`event_id`, `event_name`, `event_desc`, `event_date`) VALUES
(1, 'Culture Night', 'all about culture', '2013-05-16'),
(2, 'Sports Night', 'all about sports', '2013-05-31'),
(3, 'Random Night', 'randomness overloaded', '2013-06-15'),
(4, 'Winter Fest', 'the awesome winter fest', '2013-11-20'),
(5, 'Archived Event', 'this event has been occured in past', '2013-04-02');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cfs_parents` (
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cfs_registrations` (
  `registration_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `certificate_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `emergency_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `child_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`registration_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `certificate_id_UNIQUE` (`certificate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `wp_cfs_registrations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `certificate_id` FOREIGN KEY (`certificate_id`) REFERENCES `wp_cfs_certificates` (`certificate_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: If you run those queries separably is it still the second query that trigger the error?

Comment: Nope its running fine. Weird!

Comment: which version of mysql? i m not getting any error. See the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c52

Comment: @AshReva 5.5.25a - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I've seen this before, when running queries in phpmyadmin - it has something to do with assigning not null. I ended up getting rid of all the not null declarations, and then setting them by hand later. Hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @L_Holcombe I think I figured it out. But just trying to make sure if I am correct before I post the answer.

Comment: In sql fiddle i ran on 5.5.30. Is it possible for you to upgrade to 5.5.30?

Comment: @AshReva I think you didn't get the point my friend. Try running that code inside mysql_query() in PHP. It wont work then.

Comment: From the php manual pages on mysql_query() - "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier". You are sending multiple queries there

Comment: mysqli supports sending multiple queries. mysql is deprecated, so you shouldn't be using it at all in new code.

Answer (score 3):

Its because `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries

Its mentioned in the official PHP documentation

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.